# run an exe for self changing name directory batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, exe, portable-executable

i want to create a portable roblox but these bothers me
i am not so good at batch file but how to i run these exe under these directory i mean
if roblox has an update the "version-3bxxxxxxxx" will change and i cannot run the exe anymore

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-3b33190189084158\RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe" -app

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-3b33190189084158\RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe" -app

i try to search on the internet give nothing more =(

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found the help you needed by now, sad no one responded after all this time. This is not as elegant, but I had the same issue and I did this as my solution:

`cd\Progra~2\Roblox\Versions\version-*` <-just need a "*" wildcard there

`start RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe -app`

Hope this helps others that want to run a batch file for programs like Discord and Roblox etc. as their directory names always change with updates.... The practice is annoying and I wish devs would consider end users setups.

Comment: this question slipped my attention. Added a batch script solution.

Answer (score 0):

rEd2k's answer is fine for use directly on the command line. With a batch script, you can automate it.

Search for the exact folder name with a `for /d` loop and use the found folder as working folder with the `start` command:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Roblox\Versions\version-*") do set "rootdir=%%a"
start /d "%rootdir%" RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe -app
```

NOTE: if there is more than one matching folder (versions), `rootdir` will contain the *last* found folder (by string sorting on NTFS), which is probably good enough.